# Create addin for Sharepoint

Tags: visual-studio

I want to know if there's a way to create an addin for Sharepoint similar to the Outlook Plugins you can develop in Visual Studio.

I've seen I can create a "Web Part" but I don't think that's the same kind of application and I've had some problems trying to synchronize it from the server to a Sharepoint client, actually I'm not even sure that's possible.

Hopefully somebody has some sort of answer for this as I have not found much clear info. on this topic. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Look in to the App framework for SharePoint 2013. It is quite new stuff, but more and more documentation and blog posts are available online.

[Here is the MSDN startpoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/apps/fp160950.aspx) for developing both Office 2013 Apps and Sharepoint 2013 Apps.

For mor specific questions, please search this and other forums, or add a more detailed question here :)